# HttpRequestValidationException - How to get full value entered?

Tags: asp.net, validation, exception

We receive multiple HttpRequestValidationExceptions on our website.  We catch these appropriately, but would like to start logging them in more detail.  The message that is caught shows

```
"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$txtSearch=\"<a href=\"www.google.com...\")."}
```

We would like to know the full text of what was entered in the text box and will do nothing except log it.  I know that I entered

```
<a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

but as you can see, it did not show all of that in the Message part of the exception.  InnerException is null, so that is of no help.

This is the code we use:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the last exception that has occurred
    if (Server.GetLastError() != null)
    {
        var ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
        //...log it here
    }
}
```

How can we get the full text entered into the text box?  Turning off the page validation is not an option.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**Use Request.Form["key name"] after catching last exception.**

var val = Request.Form["txtInput1"];

You can also use

```
foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
        //Log everything.
         var x = Request.Form[key];
}
```

Above I had tbSource as a text box and capturing the Value on Application_Error